# SQL query with operator between and date in a strange format

Tags: sql, between

I have a column in my table that stores a date in format (DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS). For e.g.:

```
05-06-15 01:02:03
```

I need to output for instance all the records that have a date between the 4th and the 5th of June, so i tried:

```
SELECT * from table where date BETWEEN '04-06-15 00:00:00' AND '05-06-15 23:59:59'
```

But it also output results with a different month, as:

```
05-07-15 14:52:34
```

Is there a way to use a single query for solving this issue or I have to change all my database date format?

Comment: Change your columns data type to `datetime` to make use of simple comparisons

Comment: Is this actually a `datetime` datatype?  Or are you storing dates as `varchar`?

Comment: it is a varchar, but i didn't build the database, I found it like this and I was trying to avoid editing every query by changing to datetime type

Comment: String comparisons aren't going to work here.  You're going to have to convert the varchar columns in the table to datetime, or you're going to have to convert the values to datetime in the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
from table 
where 
STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y %T')  between 
'2015-06-05 00:00:00' and '2015-06-5 23:59:59';
```